# Combining multiple applications in a single package

Tags: package

We have 4 to 5 applications in a single org.Is there a way to bundle everything into a single package or should we create separate org's for each applications to create the same?

Expert advice needed please..

Comment: We have approx 45 apps in a one production org. I believe you try to migrate meta data that belongs to multiple apps from one org to another using a package xml  ?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Deploy to one org? Deploy to many orgs? Release a package on the AppExchange?

Comment: Release a package on the app exchange